# Qt closes immediatly when importing uia model

Tags: debian, qt, development

I have installed Qt 5.15.1 recently (full framework). I could not import Qt 3D presentation to a Qt design studio or Qt Creator (Qt Quick 2) projects. When importing via **library->Assets->Add New Assets...** Qt crashes.

Have any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution for this error. **changing the version number from 7 to 5 in .uip (Qt 3D presentation file) file resolved this issue** in Qt 5.15.1.